# tracking all online users in Volt

Tags: ruby, voltrb

I'm trying to make a record of all the users which are currently online.

Here's what I've tried:

- In my "main_controller":

  channel.on('connect') { puts "ON"; store._online_users << Volt.current_user.to_h }
   channel.on('disconnect') { puts "OFF"; store._online_users.delete(Volt.current_user.to_h) }

In my "main.html":

```
  {{store._online_users.each do |user| }}
    {{user.to_h}} <br>
  {{end}}
```

The problem is, at some point when testing this I ended up with around a dozen entries in the `store._online_users` list. I want to delete them all, but I can't get it to work. I've tried:

- `store._online_users.clear` **has no effect**
- `store._online_users.each(&:destroy)` **no effect**
- `store._online_users = []` **no effect**

**Edit**

So, since originally posting this question, I've realized that `Volt.current_user` is nil unless somebody has logged in through the auth system.

There's still the problem of undeletable records in my `store._online_users`, so I'm trying a different key.

I tried the following, but `store._current_users` always remains empty:

```
  channel.on('connect') {
    Volt.current_user.then { |user|
      unless user.nil?
        store._current_users << user
      end
    }
  }
  channel.on('disconnect') {
    Volt.current_user.then { |user|
      unless user.nil?
        store._current_users.delete(user)
      end
    }
  }
```

How would i make a ModelArray which contains all currently online users?

Comment: What does your store model look like?

Comment: I see a possible mixup of _online_users and _current_users, which association are you using? Could this be the problem?

Comment: @Ronna I started trying to use `online_users`. But then I ended up with a bunch of records in there that I didn't know how to delete. That's when I switched to `current_users`. By the way, `store` is not a model, it is a built in keyword in Volt.

Comment: I found this test in their code base, they expect it to fail, but I didn't find the corresponding issue to confirm it's just buggy - https://github.com/voltrb/volt/blob/f942b92385adbc894ee4a37903ee6a9c1a65e9a4/spec/integration/first_last_spec.rb